# Scanner read an array of inputs from console

Tags: java, c#

Hi how can i achieve the same effect in java?
The code below is in C#.

```
 for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++)
{
           string[] arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
           arr[arr_i] = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp,Int32.Parse);
}
```

Comment: You should try to implement this yourself first. There is a lot of documentation available on how to read input and how to store it. You can find more Java details in the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java `split()` method returns an array of `String`. You have to parse the individual `String` in the array to `Integer`.

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] data = in.nextLine().split(" ");
    int[] numbers = new int[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're working with jagged arrays in `C#` where each element of the array is another array. In `Java` you'll need to use a `Scanner#nextLine()` to imitate `Console.ReadLine()` in `C#`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
...
...
...
for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++)
{
     String[] arr_temp = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
     arr[arr_i] = Arrays.stream(arr_temp).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

in `Java 8` you can use [`Stream#mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to imitate [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) in `C#`.